# Python Twitter library: cannot import it

Tags: python, importerror, python-twitter

I'm trying this presumably basic thing of importing [Python Twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) library.

First I got an error in line 52, saying he couldn't upload a json library. That line of code is part of script where the library decides which json library it should import based on Python's version.
I commented all lines addressing other versions of Python than the one I'm using and it worked.

Then another error popped up:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
 import twitter
    File "C:\Python32\lib\twitter.py", line 3448
 except urllib2.HTTPError, http_error:
                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This one I don't understand.

I tried importing this in versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2.2, but none worked.
In one I was asked for the oauth library, then oauth2. The first one I got right, the second one couldn't.

I think this should work in 3.2.2. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That exception you mentioned is a syntax error for Python 2 code that's trying to run in python 3. I can tell because of the except syntax.

How did you install the package?

easy_install or pip?

Comment: I had the same! I think it's a compatibility problem. The module works fine with python 2.7 but not with 3.1, 3.1 or 2.6 version.

Answer (score 2):

That exception you mentioned is a syntax error for Python 2 code that's trying to run in python 3. I can tell because of the except syntax.

From the project page:

```
Install the dependencies:

http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/simplejson
http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/
http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2
```

from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/

`easy_install python-twitter` or `pip install python-twitter` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the installed library to be able to import pytwitter on python 3:

```
pip uninstall python-twitter
pip install python-twitter-v2
```